# How to write a measure that works with any date dimension to show last year value?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create a measure that can be added next to any date dimension. For example: next to year, months, week or date.

And accordingly it must show the value last year.

So if it is added next to year, then it must display value last year.

If next to year week, then value same week last year.

If next to year week day, then value same day last year.

The measure I have created is:

```
SALES_LY =

VAR last_YR = MAX(CALENDARTBL[YR])-1

CALCULATE(SUM[SALES], REMOVEFILTERS(CALENDERTBL), CALENDARTBL[YR]=last_YR)
```

But if I place this next to year then it works as expected - that is - shows last year sales value.

But if I place next to week or date then it still shows last year value.

I'm trying:

```
SALES_LY =

VAR last_YR = MAX(CALENDARTBL[YR])-1

VAR startdt = 
CALCULATE(MIN(CALENDARTBL[YR]), REMOVEFILTERS(CALENDARTBL), CALENDARTBL[YR]= last_YR

VAR enddt = 
CALCULATE(MAX(CALENDARTBL[YR]), REMOVEFILTERS(CALENDARTBL), CALENDARTBL[YR]= last_YR

CALCULATE(SUM[SALES], REMOVEFILTERS(CALENDERTBL), CALENDARTBL[Date]>=startdt,
CALENDARTBL[Date]<=enddt )
```

Is there a simpler way?

Maybe as follows:

```
Sales LY =   

var cy = MAX(calendar[yr])   

var days = VALUES(calendar[DayNumber])   

RETURN CALCULATE([Sales], REMOVEFILTERS(calendar), calendar[yr] = cy-1 && calendar[DayNumber] IN days     )
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SALES_LY = CALCULATE(SUM[SALES], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(CALENDARTBL[Date]) )
```

See more info on [Time intelligence functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax)

Alternative solution without Time intelligence:

```
SALES_LY =
  var cMin = MIN(CALENDARTBL[Date])
  var cMax = MAX(CALENDARTBL[Date])
  var lyMin = DATE( YEAR(cMin) - 1, MONTH(cMin), DAY(cMin) )
  var lyMax = DATE( YEAR(cMax) - 1, MONTH(cMax), DAY(cMax) )
  return
    CALCULATE(
      SUM[SALES],
      ALL(CALENDARTBL),
      lyMin <= CALENDARTBL[Date] && CALENDARTBL[Date] <= lyMax
    )
```

Another one worth trying with your setup:

```
SALES_LY =
  CALCULATE(
    SUM[SALES],
    DATEADD(CALENDARTBL[Date], -1, YEAR) 
  )
```

Or:

```
SALES_LY =
  CALCULATE(
    SUM[SALES],
    PREVIOUSYEAR(CALENDARTBL[Date]) 
  )
```

Comment: Due to certain reasons I cannot Mark the calendar table as a date table and hence I cannot use the time intelligence functions. But is this technically based on dates? Similar to my final DAX conceptually?

Comment: Try it regardless of it being marked as a Date table. But you should understand why you can't mark it as a Date table. Do you have a column in the date table that has unique consecutive dates?

Comment: No the thing is my date table has got several calendars (one per client), therefore each day repeats several times (one per client). But that's a different topic. Ignore this bit for now.

Comment: Based on simple DAX can I do `var dates = VALUES(CALENDAR[DayNumber])` and then apply this to the calculate along with year-1 ?

Comment: See above additional alternative.

Comment: How about this `Sales LY =
  var cy = MAX(calendar[yr])
  var days = VALUES(calendar[DayNumber])
  RETURN
    CALCULATE(
      [Sales],
      REMOVEFILTERS(calendar),
      calendar[yr] = cy-1 && calendar[DayNumber] IN days
    )`

Comment: Great answer Sam

Comment: @variable - if it works for you then go for it - just be aware that it will have issues if you span across more than a year.

Comment: What do you mean by issues please?

Comment: I'm assuming `[DayNumber]` repeat each year - Jan 1 = 1, Jan 2 = 2 ... Feb 1 = 32 etc... So if you want to see 13 months of the previous year, when you use `VALUES` it returns unique, non-duplicated values. So any range greater than a year, `VALUES(calendar[DayNumber])` will only give you a year's worth of days.

Comment: @SamNseir - I'm trying hard to understand in what scenario will I want to see 13 months of previous year? Can you give me an example please. Given that the measure shows the value last year, I'm assuming it will be used next to either Yr, Month, Wk or Day column in a table. Is there a scenario I have missed?